# React + MongoDB GET Request with Params How to

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, get

I'm trying to **access a document** from my MongoDB Database that **contains the name value equal to what I'm passing from my FrontEnd**. Right now, I'm getting a 200 Response, but the **data is null**, and the logs say my query is undefined, but I have no idea why.

**Here's how my BE looks like:**

```js
recordRoutes.route("/test").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let query = req.params.currentName;
  console.log('QUERY:', query);

   
  db_connect.collection("records").findOne({'name': query}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
    
  });
});
```

**And this is my call in Frontend:**

```js
 const fetchUser = useCallback(async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

       await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/test`, {params: {currentName}} )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('RESPONSE IS:', response);
           // console.log('RESPONSE.DATA:', response.data);
            //return response;
            
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('DATA IS:', data);
            setData(data);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e))
        


       //return;
      }

    , [currentName]);
```

Any idea why I'm not getting anything?

NOTE: If I'm hardcoding in my Backend **.findOne({'name': 'Test2'}**, .. etc, **it does find the document where the name is indeed Test2.**
I'm guessing there's a problem with how I'm getting the req.params.currentName, somehow.

**Any help would be HUGELY appreciated. Thank you!**

Answer (score 2):

In front-end change the request URL to this

```
await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/test/${currentName}`)
```

In the API route modify the route like this

```
recordRoutes.route("/test/:currentName").get(function (req, res) {
```